# How to extract Windows Start Menu links path

Tags: wmi

I need to extract the full path of .lnk files that are present in Windows 10 Start Menu. From the internet, I saw that I have to perform the following WMI query:

```
select * from Win32_LogicalProgramGroupItem
```

And use the Name field, which will hold the full path of the .link file. Also, from [Microsoft website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-), an example of the expected result is provided:

```
Example: "C:\Users\someone\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Accessories\NotePad.Lnk"
```

Unfortunately, the obtained result is a following:

```
Default:Start Menu\Programs\desktop.ini
```

Any idea, how I can extract the full path please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Environment.SpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) enum to get the `StartMenu` path.
After it, you could simple iterate over the directory lnk objects.

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.StartMenu);

foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folder,"*.lnk",SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Tested on Win10, 64-bit.